# Save "apt-get" apps onto a USB

Tags: usb, live-usb

I'm running Ubuntu live off a USB, I do not want to install it though. On the same USB I have a second partition to save files on. How would I save 'apt-get install ***' and Software Store apps onto my second patition?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean you want the debs downloaded by apt to be cached on the second partition instead of in the running partition, as a way to save space?

Comment: `apt-get download <pkg>` in the directory you want to save it in should do. This won't grab dependencies, though.

Comment: @zwets Not originally, I wanted to save the downloaded apps on the USB but found out that is impossible. Now your way seems easier. How would I get deb for any app?

Answer (score 0):

If it is your intention to cache the debs downloaded by apt on the second partition instead of in the primary, then you could do that this way:

```
# assuming the second partition is mounted at /mnt/second
# move the existing cache over to the second partition
sudo mv /var/cache/apt /mnt/second/apt-cache

# symlink the original name to the new location
sudo ln -s /mnt/second/apt-cache /var/cache/apt
```